# Datatables date sort with deferRender

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using deferRender to populate my datatable, however, I am still trying to accomplish my sorting on the client side (not server side).

Previously I've used HTML5 data attributes (http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) but I'm not sure how I could use that with deferRender.

I have tried to use the datetime-moment.js plugin (https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) but no sorting is applied whatsoever to the date column with this applied (the other table columns still sort).

I define my table with:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );

$("#my_table").dataTable({
  dom: "Bfrtip",
  ajax: {
    "url": $('#my_table').data('json-source'),
    "dataSrc": ""
  },
  deferRender: true
});
```

**UPDATE**

I tried using the HTML5 data attributes with the createdRow callback with no success:

```
createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
  var rowDate = $(row).find('td').eq(3).text();
  var dateOrderDate = moment(rowDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYYMMDD");
  $(row).find('td').eq(3).attr("data-order", dateOrderDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
  },

  "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },

  "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
  }
});

$("#my_table").dataTable({
  dom: "Bfrtip",
  ajax: {
    "url": $('#my_table').data('json-source'),
    "dataSrc": ""
  },
  deferRender: true,
  aoColumns: [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { sType: "date-uk" },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]  
});
```